# Can i get the icon image of an app through adb

Tags: android, adb

I want to access an app's icon through adb. How can I do that? I mean, is there any path in the mobile where the icons are stored. I was able to get the name of the packages through pm command and also through the /data/app directory.

Comment: Have you got any answer i see there is no icon in package

Answer (score 2):

An app package usually contains multiple icons (for different display resolutions, etc). The actual icon image that your device's launcher shows to you is stored in the launcher app's properties. In case of the latest default Android launcher it is stored in `/data/data/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/databases/app_icons.db` database.

Comment: Which format is this? How can i access an inage?